# Filter data frame by multiple conditions stored in one string, using gganimate

Tags: r, dplyr, gganimate

I am trying to create a scatter plot animation using `gganimate` by creating a shifting window that filters data points. I have used the `transition_filter` function to create the animation. Instead of manually writing out all of the filtering conditions, I created a string of all the conditions in a loop, with the intention of converting it into something recognizable by `transition_filter`.

Here is my code:

```r
require(ggplot2)
require(gganimate)

df <- data.frame(x = runif(1000), y = runif(1000), f = runif(1000))

conds <- ""

for (i in 1:30) {
  conds <- paste0(conds, 0.5 + 0.01 * i, " <= f & f < ", 0.7 + 0.01 * i, ", ")
}

ggplot(df) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  transition_filter(transition_length = 2,
                    filter_length = 1,
                    !!rlang::parse_expr(conds)) + 
  enter_fade() + 
  ggtitle('{closest_expression}')
```

Despite my efforts, I keep receiving an error message:

```
Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) (temp.R#802): <text>:1:21: unexpected ','
1: 0.51 >= f & f > 0.71,
                        ^
```

How can I convert the string of conditions into something that `transition_filter` or `dplyr::filter` can recognize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to create a vector of conditions not one long string. Second, as we are now have a vector use `rlang::parse_exprs`. Finally, use the unsplice operator `!!!` to pass your filter conditions to `transition_filter`:

Note: Check your filter conditions. Your conditions return an empty dataset, e.g. for `i = 1` I use `f >= 0.51 & f < 0.71` while in your code it's `0.51 >= f & f > .71` which is `FALSE` for all `f`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(x = runif(100), y = runif(100), f = runif(100))

n <- 30
conds <- paste0("f >= ", 0.5 + 0.01 * seq(n), " & f < ", 0.7 + 0.01 * seq(n))

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  transition_filter(
    transition_length = 2,
    filter_length = 1,
    !!!rlang::parse_exprs(conds)
  ) +
  enter_fade() +
  ggtitle(
    "Filter: {closest_filter}",
    subtitle = "{closest_expression}"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I have corrected my example code. Well done!